# How to name datafield in CoreDNS ConfigMap configuration

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, configmap, coredns

I have configured coreDNS to point to an external DNS server for all `*.mydomain.com` requests with this `yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  test.server: |
    mydomain.com:53 {
        errors
        cache 30
        forward . 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.4
    }
```

Now what I couldn't find is what the **test.server** part is for. [I found that `.server` is important](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/aks/coredns-custom#custom-proxy-server), but not how to properly name this part, let alone what to call this part.

Comment: looking at the examples there, i dont think it matters? as long as its called `%name%.server`

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigMaps` use *key*-*value* pairs to organize the data contained in them. [Here is a good example of this format for the data section of a ConfigMap](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/configmaps.html#overview).

For this specifically, it looks like `coreDNS` in AKS will identify the proxy-related configuration [as long as the *key* matches `*.server`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/coredns-custom.md#custom-proxy-server).

So in your case, the data property called `test.server` contains configuration information regarding `mydomain.com:53` among other nested configuration data. This format is specific to `coreDNS` configuration on AKS.

Answer (score 0):

`test.server` is just the key from your ConfigMap containing the configuration properties for the server.

---

As the second example (on the AKS docs page you linked) says:

> test.server: | # you may select any name here, but it must end with the .server file extension

---

Meaning Azure Kubernetes Service will probably search for keys ending in .server and use them accordingly. Naming could be anything from `external.server`, `dns.server` or `coredns.server` to just keeping `test.server`.